# Is there a way to check only first data byte from remote url using NSData?

Tags: ios, image, request, nsdata, imagedownload

I've this problem in this context:

I receive from url a json with some options of images like:

```
var original    : String?
var small       : String?
var medium      : String?
var large       : String?
```

Only original is right that exists, but can be very big/heavy. So I want to check if the others size image exists. Before create the object I just check for images like this:

*(before call this method I check for url string availability - url can exist without content)

```
func checkResourceIsReachable(url: String) -> String{
    var urlReachable = ""
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    do {
        let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
        print(data)
        urlReachable = String(url)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        if let _ = original{
            urlReachable = original!
        } else{
            urlReachable = "erro"
        }
    }

    return urlReachable
}
```

But, that way is downloading all data if existis (NSDataReadingOptions),
so, anyone knows a way to check only first byte from url content? I couldn't find anything yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may do a HTTP HEAD request.

Comment: Hi @Larme! But in that case, I have to create a header with that info, right?

Comment: The server should respond you with the size of the object. It's less heavy than downloading the whole image. For instance, it should responds you "250Mo".  Then if it's okay, you can download it correctly.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that! Thanks @Larme!

Comment: @Larme, by the way.. You know how I do this with alamofire? .-.

Comment: I don't (I don't "speak" Swift), my guess is that on your `(NS)URLRequest`, you set the `HTTPMethod` to "HEAD", or simply use `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks anyway, I've tried something.. looks like it works!